# Handling Dates/Times with WebApi and Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using MVC WebApi and Knockout to load/save data.  I am using the mapping plugin with knockout so I can simply return an object via the api without the need to 'push' elements into the model.  All this works ok, however, I now come across a need to be able to change two types of field, a date and a time.  Both are held in the database as a DateTime.

What would you guys recommend is the best way to handle date/time in this way, I have created my own binding handlers to format them correctly when displaying, but altering them and saving them is my concern.  I can use something like a jQuery DatePicker but will this set the value of the date field correctly so that when the object is 'put' to the webapi it will be able to update it correctly?

Comment: try this http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ check the example section

Comment: Not stuck with a plugin to use, more about storing the value back again in an EF object mapped to knockout so I can use ajax to 'put' the object

Comment: Just to be clear, the EF Model is not mapped to Knockout, it's JSON representation is used to create a JavaScript object that is mapped. So, you need to go in the opposite direction: JavaScript (Knockout) => JSON (HTTP) => Model (WebAPI) => EF. Really, it becomes a question of how the JSON data auto-maps to a DateTime value in WebAPI.

Comment: I realise that it's not mapped directly hence why I wondered how others would set the JSON representation to some kind of date/time picker that would also store the JSON value back when changed to upload back to WebApi